# POST json into WCF service returning (400 BAD request)

Tags: json, wcf

I Trying to POST a json data into self hosted WCF service

POST is working good when json string such as

```
{"data": "testdata"}
```

same POST is doesn't working and returning 400 (Bad Request) error message when json string as

```
{data: [{
     data1: "testvalue1",
     data2: "testvalue2",
     data3: "testvalue3",
     data4: "testvalue4",
}]
}
```

And this is my WCF service Code

```
<OperationContract>
<WebInvoke(Method:="POST", ResponseFormat:=WebMessageFormat.Json, RequestFormat:=WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle:=WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped)>
Private Function DoWork(ByVal data As string) As system.servicemodel.channels.message

    // DO SOMETHING WITH DATA

end function
```

What is difference between json string and nested json string in my case

And how can i solve my problem

Thanks.

Comment: It depends on the BodyStyle property. you could refer to my previous reply, feel free to contact me if there is anything I can help with.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52489002/get-the-object-is-null-using-json-in-wcf-service/52497740#52497740

Comment: Isn't your `nested json string` actually an array?

Answer (score 0):

WCF cannot deserialize complex object represented in json into `string`. In order to make the example work you need to accept a collection of complex objects in operation

```
//complex object class
[DataContract]
public class DataModel
{
    [DataMember(Name = "data1")]
    public string Data1 { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "data2")]
    public string Data2 { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "data3")]
    public string Data3 { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "data4")]
    public string Data4 { get; set; }
}

private Message DoWork(List<DataModel> data)
```