# receiving post request through postman into wcf

Tags: c#, asp.net, rest, wcf, postman

I'm trying to receive an XML [post] message coming from Postman using WCF there are man things that I need to know first what type of data coming from rest is it for example Stream, XML, HttpRequest.
I built this simple receiver but so far it's not working.

```
    [WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "/PostMessage", Method = "POST")]
    public String InsertMessage(XmlEntity value)
    {
        String re = null;
        foreach (XmlNode node in value.ChildNodes)
        {
            string text = node.InnerText; 
            string tag = node.Name;

        }
    re = text;
  }
```

also if Postman is sending Post to my project wouldn't my method become get type?

how can I reach each tag inside the xml request and their respective values?

Postman Sending me this error 400 Encountered invalid root element name 'Messages'. 'root' is the only allowed root element name.

Answer (score 0):

The type of the XmlEnity could not be serialized and deserialized properly in WCF.  We had better use strong-typed data and decorate the custom class with DataContract attribute.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/using-data-contracts
XML and JSON data format in SOAP message is implemented by the WCF framework itself.

```
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST",
  ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml,
   RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml,
  BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest,
        UriTemplate ="BookInfo/")]
```

Please refer to the example in the reply.
[Get the object is null using JSON in WCF Service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52489002/get-the-object-is-null-using-json-in-wcf-service/52497740#52497740)
Feel free to let me know if there is anything I can help with.