# can't receive xml post request values in wcf c#

Tags: c#, rest, wcf

I'm experimenting with WCF and built a standard product class with id and name parameters, my goal is to receive it from rest, and return status.

```
[DataContract]
    public partial class Product {
        [DataMember]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
    [DataContract]
    public class Message
    {
        [DataMember]
        public bool isSucceed { get; set; }
    }
```

with relative Post Method to

```
[WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "ProductPingXML", Method = "POST", 
            RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml)]
        [Description("Recive Post Message")]
        public Message PingXmlProduct(Product Input)
        {
            Message message = new Message();
            //Todo Capture what rest send 
            if (Input == null)
            {
                message.isSucceed = false;
            }
            else
            {
                message.isSucceed = true;
            }

            // strip the xml from the body

            // Assign the values to the new obj class Product
            return message;
        }
```

and I'm trying to call it through postman using this XML found in the XML help schema.

```
<Product xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/RestML.Data">
  <Id>2147483647</Id>
  <Name>String content</Name>
</Product>
```

Working with WCF is relatively new to me, so I might miss something here. so my question is:
how can I receive the postman XML inside PingXmlProduct and assign the respective values into new obj;

Comment: At that point (inside the `PingXmlProduct` method) the xml will already be 'stripped from the body' by the WCF framework. You will simply have an instance of the class `Product` assigned to the `Input` variable, with properties Id and Name filled with the values from the xml.

Comment: Ok if I try to request post with xml i get "Could not get any response" From Postman?  Is it because the response is a string and not in xml

Comment: What's the statuscode? 404? That would mean 'not found'. I'd recommend to take next steps based on the statuscode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We should create Restful style WCF service by using webhttpbinding. Please refer to the below configuration.

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="Server1.MyService">
        <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="Server1.IService" behaviorConfiguration="rest"></endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"></endpoint>
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost:5577"/>
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="rest">
          <webHttp/>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Then we should specify the webmessagebodystyle.

```
[OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(BodyStyle =WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare)]
        void GetData(Product product);
```

Assumed that there is the below definition.

```
[DataContract]
    public class Product
    {
        [DataMember]
        public int ID { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string Name { get; set; }

}
```

We could call the service like the below way in Postman(please pay attention to the namespace of the custom class).
[image]
Please refer to my previous reply related to the WebMessageBodyStyle property.
[Get the object is null using JSON in WCF Service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52489002/get-the-object-is-null-using-json-in-wcf-service/52497740#52497740)
Feel free to let me know if the problem still exists.