# Dialogflow Fulfillment with WCF REST Post Method not receiving data

Tags: c#, visual-studio, wcf, post, dialogflow-es

I created a WCF service as follows:

```
[OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "/GetOrder", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, Method = "POST")]
        string GetOrder(BotInterface order);
```

GetOrder is already been created and for now it is just returning a string, I just wanted to test the request.  If I triggered the intent with the fulfillment configured my local code its been executed but the order object is always null.  If I use request.bin the post json data is there and if I call the service using soapui also works, it is just dialogflow.

any clues?

Answer (score 1):

By default, the **RequestFormat** is XML data format.
We should specify the request body as XML format.

```
<Product xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/RestML.Data">
  <Id>2147483647</Id>
  <Name>String content</Name>
</Product>
```

Here is an example.
[can't receive xml post request values in wcf c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57394808/cant-receive-xml-post-request-values-in-wcf-c-sharp/57427593#57427593)

Here is a detailed description about the data format when posting the parameter.
[Get the object is null using JSON in WCF Service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52489002/get-the-object-is-null-using-json-in-wcf-service/52497740#52497740)
Feel free to let me know if the problem still exists.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I tried my service using json request from SOAPUI and worked perfectly. I found that the issue was on the request mapping from my app, when I converted the json payload into a C# object there was an element that was repeated as an element and a Type and I had to change the name making the post to failed.  That is why it was always null.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help Abraham! The solution was: I tried my service using json request from SOAPUI and worked perfectly. I found that the issue was on the request mapping from my app, when I converted the json payload into a C# object there was an element that was repeated as an element and a Type and I had to change the name making the post to failed. That is why it was always null.