# Attachment data send from Soap UI is not received in WCF service

Tags: c#, wcf, soapui, soap-client, mtom

I have  a wcf service that looks for a stream data

```
[MessageContract]
public class NextService : INextService
{  
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "*")]
    public void Upload(Stream data)
    {
        try
        {
            _log.InfoFormat("-------------{0}------------------------------", data);
            


            var request = WebOperationContext.Current.IncomingRequest;
            WebHeaderCollection headers = request.Headers;
            _log.InfoFormat(request.Method + " ");// + request.UriTemplateMatch.RequestUri.AbsolutePath);
            foreach (string headerName in headers.AllKeys)
            {
                _log.InfoFormat(headerName + ": " + headers[headerName]);
            }

            if (File.Exists(@"c:\\test\\ViewDocumentOp.pdf"))
                File.Delete(@"c:\\test\\ViewDocumentOp.pdf");
            using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"c:\\test\\ViewDocumentOp.pdf", FileMode.CreateNew, FileAccess.Write))
            {
                CopyStream(data, fs);
            }

            StreamReader bodyReader = new StreamReader(data);
            string bodyString = bodyReader.ReadToEnd();
            int length = bodyString.Length;
            _log.InfoFormat("-------------------------------------------------------");

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _log.ErrorFormat(" Error in UploadDoc {0} Message : {1}", ex.StackTrace, ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Following is the interface

```
 [ServiceContract]
    public interface INextService
    {
        [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare)]
            void Upload(Stream data);
    }
```

I have added  webconfig with MTOM details in binding

```
       <basicHttpBinding>
                <binding name="Encode" messageEncoding="Mtom" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
                         transferMode="Streamed">
              </binding>                  
         </basicHttpBinding>
    <service behaviorConfiguration="NextServiceBehavior" name="SupportingDocsFacade.NextService">
            <endpoint address="/Upload" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="Encode"
              name="Basic" contract="SupportingDocsFacade.INextGenService" />
            <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpsBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
          </service>
```

I am using Soap UI to call this
There is an attachment also. The raw data shown in SoapUI is having boundary data
[image: Soap XML data] [image]
I have enabled  MTOM in the request property as per following [SoapDoc](https://www.soapui.org/docs/soap-and-wsdl/attachments.html) [image: Enable MTOM]

Some how the data is not reaching the webservice ..  The log print in Upload service is

> -------------System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.StreamFormatter+MessageBodyStream------------------------------
> [image: Data Error]

Answer (score 0):

First, we could not directly post the data(call the service) to the service address created by Basichttpbinding. This only applies to the WCF rest style service created by Webhttpbinding.
[can't receive xml post request values in wcf c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57394808/cant-receive-xml-post-request-values-in-wcf-c-sharp/57427593#57427593)

> http://xxxx:xx/service1.svc/upload

If we use Basichttpbinding to create service, we should use the base address to pass the stream data, as mentioned in the document.
https://www.soapui.org/docs/soap-and-wsdl/attachments.html
we take advantage of inline files to pass the stream parameter. see the screenshot below.
[image]
Feel free to let me know if there is anything I can help with.