# How to call RestFul WCF POST service With Custom Object using POSTMAN or any client tool application?

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, soapui, restful-url

okay lets say I want to use POSTMAN or any other Rest service client tool to call my code, how should can I do it? one of my parameters is SwitchStatus (it's some object i defined myself)

When calling this service with POSTMAN, should I include something within the body of the request? If so, what will be the format?
any help would be appreciated it

Thanks

```
        [WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "/SwitchStatus", Method = "POST")]
        [OperationContract]
        [Description("Request to update switch status, true for close the switch")]
        void UpdateSwitchStatus(SwitchStatus data);
```

I will expect my server to receive the request from POSTMAN.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buddy, You are right, we should consider whether including the name of the parameter. Actually it is determined by the Bodystyle property.

```
[OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(RequestFormat =WebMessageFormat.Json,ResponseFormat =WebMessageFormat.Json,BodyStyle =WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare)]
        CompositeType GetDataUsingDataContract(CompositeType composite);

    [DataContract]
    public class CompositeType
    {
        bool boolValue = true;
        string stringValue = "Hello ";

        [DataMember]
        public bool BoolValue
        {
            get { return boolValue; }
            set { boolValue = value; }
        }

        [DataMember]
        public string StringValue
        {
            get { return stringValue; }
            set { stringValue = value; }
        }
}
```

Depending on the above BodyStyle property, the request body is,

```
{"StringValue":"Hello","BoolValue":true}
```

[image]
Please refer to my previous reply. There is a meticulous description in it.
[Get the object is null using JSON in WCF Service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52489002/get-the-object-is-null-using-json-in-wcf-service/52497740#52497740)
Feel free to let me know if there is anything I can help with.