# WCF restful application PUT, POST, DELETE receive the same error: "the method is not allowed."

Tags: c#, rest, wcf

I create a server implemented on WCF with RESTFUL architecture. Written in C # using Entity Framework and MySQL DB. Code is given below. VS does not produce any errors, the GET method works fine, it outputs data from the database. However, all other methods (PUT, POST, DELETE, GetDetails) receive the same error: "the method is not allowed." Maybe you could tell what is my mistake?
If a few mistakes, then I will be grateful. I just started to study this, so I admit that there can be many mistakes.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.Web;

namespace WcfRestFullService
{
   [DataContract]
    public class CustomerDataContract
    {
        [DataMember]
        public string Id_Cus { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string FirstName_Cus { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string LastName_Cus { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string PhoneNum_Cus { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string Email_Cus { get; set; }
    }
}
```

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceModel.Web;
using System.Text;

namespace WcfRestFullService
{
    // NOTE: You can use the "Rename" command on the "Refactor" menu to change the interface name "ICustomerSevice" in both code and config file together.
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface ICustomerSevice
    {
          [OperationContract]
          [WebInvoke(Method = "GET", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
              ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, UriTemplate = "/GetAllCustomer/")]//ok
          List<CustomerDataContract> GetAllCustomer();

         [OperationContract]
         [WebGet(RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
          ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
          UriTemplate = "/CustomerDetails/{Id_Cus}")]
         CustomerDataContract CustomerDetails(String Id_Cus);

        [OperationContract]
         [WebInvoke(Method = "DELETE", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
          RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
          BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare)]
         void DeleteCustomer(String Id_Cus);

         [OperationContract]
         [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
          RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
          BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped,
          UriTemplate = "/InsertCustomer/")]//problem
         void InsertCustomer(CustomerDataContract customerDataContract);

         [OperationContract]
         [WebInvoke(Method = "PUT",ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
          RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
          BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare,
          UriTemplate = "/UpdateCustomer/")]//problem
         void UpdateCustomer(CustomerDataContract customerDataContract);
    }
}
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.8" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.8" />
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>

    <services>
      <service name="WcfRestFullService.CustomerSevice"  behaviorConfiguration="serviceBehavior">
        <endpoint address=""
                  binding="webHttpBinding"
                  contract="WcfRestFullService.ICustomerSevice"
                  behaviorConfiguration="web"></endpoint>
        </service>
          </services>

    <!--<services>
      <service name="WcfRestFullService.CustomerPreferences"  behaviorConfiguration="serviceBehavior">
        <endpoint address=""
                  binding="webHttpBinding"
                  contract="WcfRestFullService.ICustomerPreferences"
                  behaviorConfiguration="web"></endpoint>
      </service>
    </services>-->


      <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="web">
          <webHttp />
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="serviceBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
        </behavior>
        <behavior name="">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <protocolMapping>
      <add binding="webHttpBinding" scheme="https" />
    </protocolMapping>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
    <!--
        To browse web app root directory during debugging, set the value below to true.
        Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing web app folder information.
      -->
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true" />
  </system.webServer>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.6.0" newVersion="4.0.6.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Memory" publicKeyToken="cc7b13ffcd2ddd51" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.1.1" newVersion="4.0.1.1" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives" publicKeyToken="adb9793829ddae60" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.1.2.0" newVersion="3.1.2.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions" publicKeyToken="adb9793829ddae60" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.1.2.0" newVersion="3.1.2.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions" publicKeyToken="adb9793829ddae60" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.1.2.0" newVersion="3.1.2.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Abstractions" publicKeyToken="adb9793829ddae60" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.1.2.0" newVersion="3.1.2.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Extensions.Options" publicKeyToken="adb9793829ddae60" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.1.2.0" newVersion="3.1.2.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions" publicKeyToken="adb9793829ddae60" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.1.2.0" newVersion="3.1.2.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection" publicKeyToken="adb9793829ddae60" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.1.2.0" newVersion="3.1.2.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.ComponentModel.Annotations" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.2.1.0" newVersion="4.2.1.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="MySql.Data" publicKeyToken="c5687fc88969c44d" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-8.0.19.0" newVersion="8.0.19.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" publicKeyToken="adb9793829ddae60" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.1.2.0" newVersion="3.1.2.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Abstractions" publicKeyToken="adb9793829ddae60" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.1.2.0" newVersion="3.1.2.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging" publicKeyToken="adb9793829ddae60" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.1.2.0" newVersion="3.1.2.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource" publicKeyToken="cc7b13ffcd2ddd51" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.5.0" newVersion="4.0.5.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Numerics.Vectors" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.1.4.0" newVersion="4.1.4.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Buffers" publicKeyToken="cc7b13ffcd2ddd51" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.3.0" newVersion="4.0.3.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions" publicKeyToken="cc7b13ffcd2ddd51" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.2.0.1" newVersion="4.2.0.1" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Google.Protobuf" publicKeyToken="a7d26565bac4d604" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.11.4.0" newVersion="3.11.4.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="BouncyCastle.Crypto" publicKeyToken="0e99375e54769942" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.8.5.0" newVersion="1.8.5.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational" publicKeyToken="adb9793829ddae60" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.1.2.0" newVersion="3.1.2.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <entityFramework>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
      <!--<provider invariantName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices, MySql.Data.Entity.EF6, Version=6.10.9.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d">
      </provider>-->
      <provider invariantName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices, MySql.Data.EntityFramework, Version=8.0.19.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="MySQLEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Model.Model.csdl|res://*/Model.Model.ssdl|res://*/Model.Model.msl;provider=MySql.Data.MySqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;server=localhost;user id=root;password=l10ksfnq5h2c;database=chik-chak&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.Text;
using MySql.Data;
using System.Data.Entity;

using WcfRestFullService.Model;

namespace WcfRestFullService
{
    // NOTE: You can use the "Rename" command on the "Refactor" menu to change the class name "CustomerSevice" in code, svc and config file together.
    // NOTE: In order to launch WCF Test Client for testing this service, please select CustomerSevice.svc or CustomerSevice.svc.cs at the Solution Explorer and start debugging.
    public class CustomerSevice : ICustomerSevice
    {
        MySQLEntities dc;
        public CustomerSevice()
        {
            dc = new MySQLEntities();
        }

        public List<CustomerDataContract> GetAllCustomer()
        {
            var query = (from a in dc.customers
                         select a).Distinct();

            List<CustomerDataContract> CustomersList = new List<CustomerDataContract>();

            query.ToList().ForEach(x =>
            {
                CustomersList.Add(new CustomerDataContract
                {
                    Id_Cus = Convert.ToString(x.Id_Cus),
                    FirstName_Cus = x.FirstName_Cus,
                    LastName_Cus = x.LastName_Cus,
                    PhoneNum_Cus = x.PhoneNum_Cus.ToString(),
                    Email_Cus = x.Email_Cus,
                });
            });
            return CustomersList;
        }

        public CustomerDataContract CustomerDetails(string Id_Cus)
        {
            CustomerDataContract Cust = new CustomerDataContract();
            try
            {
                var query = (from a in dc.customers
                             where a.Id_Cus.Equals(Id_Cus)
                             select a).Distinct().FirstOrDefault();
                Cust.Id_Cus = query.Id_Cus.ToString();
                Cust.FirstName_Cus = query.FirstName_Cus;
                Cust.LastName_Cus = query.LastName_Cus;
                Cust.PhoneNum_Cus = query.PhoneNum_Cus.ToString();
                Cust.Email_Cus = query.Email_Cus;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new FaultException<string>(ex.Message);
            }
            return Cust;
        }

           // DELETE

          public void DeleteCustomer(string Id_Cus) 
          {
              MySQLEntities Cust = new MySQLEntities(); //check the file Model.edmx->ModelContext.tt->MySQLEntitys

              int k = Convert.ToInt32(Id_Cus);
              customer cur = (from n in dc.customers
                           where n.Id_Cus == k
                           select n).First();
              Cust.customers.Remove(cur);
              Cust.SaveChanges();
          }

          //Insert/POST

          public void InsertCustomer(CustomerDataContract customerDataContract)
          {
            MySQLEntities Cust = new MySQLEntities();
            customer cust = new customer();

              cust.Id_Cus = Convert.ToInt32(customerDataContract.Id_Cus);
              cust.FirstName_Cus = customerDataContract.FirstName_Cus;
              cust.LastName_Cus = customerDataContract.LastName_Cus;
              cust.PhoneNum_Cus = Convert.ToInt32(customerDataContract.PhoneNum_Cus);
              cust.Email_Cus = customerDataContract.Email_Cus;
              Cust.customers.Add(cust);
              Cust.SaveChanges();
          }

            //Update/PUT
          public void UpdateCustomer(CustomerDataContract customerDataContract)
          {
            //using (CustomerDataContract Cust = new CustomerDataContract())
            using (MySQLEntities Cust = new MySQLEntities()) 
            {
                  customer cust = Cust.customers.Where(n => n.Id_Cus == (Convert.ToInt32(customerDataContract.Id_Cus))).First();

                  cust.Id_Cus =Convert.ToInt32(customerDataContract.Id_Cus);
                  cust.FirstName_Cus = customerDataContract.FirstName_Cus;
                  cust.LastName_Cus = customerDataContract.LastName_Cus;
                  cust.PhoneNum_Cus =Convert.ToInt32(customerDataContract.PhoneNum_Cus);
                  cust.Email_Cus = customerDataContract.Email_Cus;

                  Cust.SaveChanges();
            }
          }
    }
}
```

```
namespace WcfRestFullService.Model
{
    using System;
    using System.Data.Entity;
    using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure;

    public partial class MySQLEntities : DbContext
    {
        public MySQLEntities()
            : base("name=MySQLEntities")
        {
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();
        }

        public virtual DbSet<customer> customers { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<customerpreference> customerpreferences { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<dish> dishes { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<dishesranking> dishesrankings { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<ingridient> ingridients { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<order> orders { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<restaraunt> restaraunts { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<type_dishes> type_dishes { get; set; }
        public object Parameters { get; internal set; }
    }
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VayJG.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CqDbf.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s2sjT.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r4qml.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gbBY1.png)

Comment: WCF is not the best tool for this.

Answer (score 1):

You should know that the default request sent by browser use `Get` HTTP verb, while the operation contract requires `DELETE` HTTP Verb.
Press F12, Network to see the details of the request.
[image]
The proper way to test `POST/DELETE/PUT` request is to send the request with `PostMan` software(or some other tool, such as `Fiddler`).
[image]
The Definition of the function.

```
[OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method ="DELETE",RequestFormat =WebMessageFormat.Json,ResponseFormat =WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    string GetResult(string id);
```

The request in Fiddler.
[image]
If the parameter is a composite type, we should pay attention to the data format of the request.
For details, see the below link.
[How to call RestFul WCF POST service With Custom Object using POSTMAN or any client tool application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58495488/how-to-call-restful-wcf-post-service-with-custom-object-using-postman-or-any-cli/58496655#58496655)
Feel free to let me know if there is anything I can help with.

Comment: I tried through Fiddler, I get errors in the PUT and POST methods (307 and then 405 errors).
And in the DELETE method "System.InvalidOperationException: 'The object cannot be deleted because it was not found in the ObjectStateManager.' " and error in VS in line:{Cust.customers.Remove(cur);}
What it can be? 
Thanks for last answer:)

Comment: This is due to that the object to be deleted is not found in the database. 
customer cur = (from n in dc.customers
                           where n.Id_Cus == k
                           select n).First();
the only parameter should be passed by the Body section instead of the query string in the URL since you use Delete verb. Like the above screenshot.

Comment: Besides, you should pay attention to the data format. I don’t see the definition of the `customdatacontract` yet. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58495488/how-to-call-restful-wcf-post-service-with-custom-object-using-postman-or-any-cli/58496655#58496655

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply! Yes, indeed, I mistakenly attached "custompreferencescontract" instead of "customdatacontract", now I've edited everything and added it correctly.
I tried to do as you recommended, but in all variations: "http://localhost: 51265 / CustomerSevice.svc/GetAllCustomer /" and even "http: // localhost: 51265 / CustomerSevice.svc / DeleteCustomer /". I do everything according to the screenshots.
If it’s not a big deal for you, maybe I'ld send you a screenshot in some messenger?
I just don’t have any understanding what I did wrong.
Thanks again for your answers.

Comment: Remove the UriTemplate and add content-type: Application/json.
I have added the definition of the method in the reply.

Comment: I did exactly according to your recommendations. Above, I changed the code, according to how it should be (URI deleted) at the top I changed the code to the final one. In addition, I added APPLICATION / JSON, but it didn’t get better, it produces the same error. Above, I attached 2 screenshots from FIDDLER and a modified DELETE method. Have I missed something?

Comment: GetAllCustomer method is Get request not DELETE. Your Uri is not right.
For Testing the DELETE method, please use the following Uri  
http://ip:portnumber/customerservice.svc/DeleteCustomer  
and add a string in request body. You have to ensure that the customer to be deleted can be found by the practical Id_cus

Comment: So, I set the URI according to your recommendations, then write Id_Cus in REQUEST BODY (I definitely know that for example Id_Cus at number 1 is in my database, i.e. when I registered it should be deleted). But when I entered everything, an error appears that was before, however, I already fixed the DELETE method. I edited my question, there are 5 attached pictures, the last three describe what actions I did, could you tell me what's wrong?
I already tried through POSTMAN, however, the same errors occur if it is easier to do through POSTMAN I will gladly do it

Comment: In the Body menu, change the Text attribute to JSON, this will add an extra http header. I.e. “content-type:application/json”. Like the above picture.

Comment: Yes, I did it, but I have the same error(the object can not be deleted, because it was not found). May be I do mistake in the DELETE method. But I checked it and did not find. 
I attached the screen of the last iteration(3-4 screen)

Comment: Add a breakpoint to check if the object can be found according to the search criteria. If indeed, I think it might relate to the EF, Such as the user in the connection string doesn’t have permission to execute deletion operation. I suggest you update the EDMX file and re-generate the data contract class.

Comment: unfortunately did not help, I tried to do it all over again

Comment: Thanks for your answers, I did it. Could you tell me what should I do next. I have 2 tables and "Id_Cus" is the primary key. I would like to know how to correctly set "Id_Cus" in the second table so that it takes the value from the first table? And where do I need to register this, in the interface where the logic of the fields is implemented and written, or in the classes where I declare them?