# Why does a WCF web service not receive the client payload?

Tags: c#, wcf

I have inherited a web service built to receive calls from a third party system, "System A". It was a POC that may not have any active functions calling it and I suspect it was only tested from SoapUI or the like and never from the application it was designed for.

When System A is configured to call it, the service is called but the payload, one complex-type parameter, is null.

I have two other web services written years ago that accept calls of the same type from the same function of System A. Pointing System A to either of these services results in the parameter being supplied. Contracts and WSDLs look very similar and the only variations I see (like differing namespaces) seem to vary between the two services that do work.

What would cause a web service to not receive the payload in the call?

Related, where should I look to find it? The parameter is getting dropped between System A calling and the web service code itself getting hit. I've checked the trace logs but see nothing that I recognize as useful.

```
namespace MyNamespace.StandardNoteReceiverService
{
    public class StandardNoteReceiverService : IReceiveNoteService
    {
        public StandardNoteReceiverResponse ReceiveNote(ReceiveNoteData standardNoteReceiverRequest)
        {
            string x = standardNoteReceiverRequest == null ? "NULL" : "ok";
            LoggingLib.Log($"Service called.  Paramter status: {x}");

            return NoteReceiverServiceLayer.ReceiveNote(standardNoteReceiverRequest);
        }
    }
}
```

which implements

```
namespace MyNamespace.StandardNoteReceiverService 
{
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IReceiveNoteService 
    {
        [OperationContract]
        StandardNoteReceiverResponse ReceiveNote(ReceiveNoteData standardNoteReceiverRequest);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It turned out to be the parameter naming.  Once I changed the name of the parameter to be the same as the name used by the services that are working, it began receiving the data.

```
public class StandardNoteReceiverService : IReceiveNoteService
{
    public StandardNoteReceiverResponse ReceiveNote(ReceiveNoteData NoteData)
    { ...
```

Answer (score 0):

How did you build “System A”? Is it a WCF Web HTTP service or an ancient soap web service? How does the client call the service and send the parameter? I think it may be that the format of the parameters sent by the client is incorrect. In the Rest-style service created by WCF, using complex objects as parameters to pass data may not always receive the value of the parameter on the server because of the format of the parameter.
[Get the object is null using JSON in WCF Service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52489002/get-the-object-is-null-using-json-in-wcf-service/52497740#52497740)
While in the WCF SOAP web service, the invocation is completed with a client proxy, the parameters are strong-typed. If the server always gets null, it might be caused by other issues.
I suggest you create a minimal, producible example so that I can try to offer a workaround instead of offering speculation of this issue here.
Feel free to let me know if the problem still exists.

Comment: Thanks, Abraham.  System A is off the shelf.  It uses .NET WCF SOAP services.  I can configure the URL it sends to, but the exact same call works on two other services we built, so the formatting wouldn't seem to be the issue.  Current path is attempting to pull from one of the working services and crossing fingers.

Comment: Mark it as an answer to help whoever encounters a similar problem.

Comment: Welll, I was going to.  Then after updating some downstream code, I rebuilt the solution and it's back to the same issue.  Back to some headscratching!